# Why isn't nginx with Puma responding?

Tags: nginx

I have an Ubuntu server that I inherited that is running nginx and Puma on a DigitalOcean droplet.  It's working as expected.  I created a snapshot of this droplet and started a new droplet based on that snapshot.  When I start it up I can't get a response from the browser.  If I do an nmap on the new droplet I see:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
8080/tcp open   http-proxy
```

If I run nmap on the droplet the snapshot was created from I see this:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   open http
443/tcp  open https
8080/tcp open   http-proxy
```

It seems like starting that droplet up based on the snapshot should bring up those services as expected.  What can I check to see why those services are closed?

Here is my nginx config:

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/home/deployer/app/shared/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    listen [::]:8080 default_server;

    root /home/deployer/app/public;

    location ^~ /assets/ {
      root /home/deployer/app/public;
      gzip_static on;
      expires max;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: The nginx logs on the second droplet.  A conflict between the two, perhaps?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Nothing in either the error or access logs to indicate a problem.

Comment: nginx is running on the second droplet?  It has permission to write to the error log?  If you check with lsof, on what ports and IP addresses is it listening?

Comment: I hadn't seen your nginx config before.  Can you give an example of an URL you give to your browser to access the second droplet?

Comment: It's just a standard http://my.domain.net URL

Comment: You can't expect that to work, since nginx is not listening on port 80.

Comment: That was my initial thought as well but then I don't understand how it's working on the original droplet?

Comment: Ah, looks like they're running haproxy on the original which doesn't have OS updates applied whereas the new droplet does.

Comment: Let us know how it goes.  So the second droplet wasn't really a snapshot?

Comment: It was but I had applied OS updates to the second droplet after standing it up that haven't been applied to the first droplet, from which the snapshot was made.  I suspect something those updates (there are over 300, it hasn't been done in a long time) has broken haproxy.